# Crear una función números decimales

Tags: javascript, regex

necesito crear una función en javascript que solo me permita ingresar en un campo de texto solo números y comas y después de la coma 2 dígitos, algo así:

**9999,99**

yo tengo esto

```
    function separadorMiles(entrada){
  var num = entrada.replace(/\./g,"");
  if(!isNaN(num)){
  num = num.toString().split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,"$1.");
  num = num.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/^[\.]/,"");
  entrada = num;
  }else{
  entrada = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,"");
  }
  return entrada;
}
```

Comment: El input tipo number no acepta valores flotantes?, de lo contrario creo que es mejor usar el input tipo number.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta funcion

```
function probarNumero(valor){
  var regexp = /^\d+\,\d{0,2}$/;
  return regexp.test(valor);
}
```

Regresa true para valor correctos. Admite desde 0 decimales hasta maximo 2